# Massive URL Decode in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, decode, encode

I have a MySQL table with 10,000+ entries. There are four columns in the table.  One of them is URL.  Some of the URL values are encoded, some are decoded.  I want to have them all be decoded.

How can I do this either with PHP directly or MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Best to do it in PHP. mysql doesn't have any native url encode/decode functions.

Comment: You don't know which will be encoded?

Comment: can you tell which rows have encoded urls and which don't?

Comment: No, I don't know which will be encoded. Wouldn't PHP's urldecode not affect an already decoded string?

Comment: Yes, it'll trash a string if you decode one that's not already encoded. E.g. `1+1=2` will be encoded as `1%2B1%3D2`. But if you urldecode `1+1=2`, you'll get `1 1=2`, becuase `+` is a url metacharacter for a 'space'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT encoded_url FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $decoded = your_function_to_decode($row['encoded_url']);
}
```

Comment: then i need to add it back into the database without loosing the order